# Correct usage of "so would" and "a priori"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Is this phrase syntactically correct?

> Because X may take different forms, ***a priori so would*** Y.

I am especially asking about the usage of "so would", but also about the place of "a priori".

Maybe it is better to say

> Because X may take different forms, ***a priori it would be the same for*** Y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both sentences in your question are correct and they mean the same thing. The syntax is different.

*Because X may take different forms, a priori so would Y.*

There's nothing ungrammatical about **a priori** here. It's functioning as an adverb meaning "based on theoretical deduction". As for *so would Y,* it is a construct used to express agreement with what has been mentioned before in the sentence. In a dialogue where you can have exactly the same construct it would sound more natural:

A: "I would definitely choose the red shirt over the yellow one."

B: "So would I."

When **so** is placed in the beginning of a sentence or a clause to express agreement, there is inversion between the auxiliary verb and the subject, in other words you write the subject-auxiliary verb in question form. The main verb is omitted. This is a shorter way of saying *I would do the same thing.*

Comment: _So_ is a "Pro-Predicate", which refers to the predicate of some preceding clause, and is used for tag agreements, like _(and) so did I_ (or in certain dialects, even [_and so didn't I_](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=1171)). The opposite is _(and) neither did I_, which refers to a negative predicate of some preceding clause.